# How to configure Webpack to load assets other than index.html from a CDN host determined at runtime?

Tags: webpack, single-page-application, cdn

We have an application where `index.html` is served from NGINX but we want all other assets to be loaded from a CDN. Our CI pipeline deploys our application to a staging environment and later to a production environment. Each environment has its own CDN (e.g., staging uses `staging.examplecdn.com` and production uses `examplecdn.com`).

It seems [Webpack's `publicPath`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/) configuration option would typically be used to define the CDN host, but it requires us to know the CDN host at build time. This would require us to build our application two times in our deployment process--once for staging and once for production. We want to avoid this, because (1) we don't want to slow down our CI pipeline and (2) it seems safer to make sure what we're deploying to production is largely what we tested in staging.

The next option Webpack documents is to [set `__webpack_public_path__`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/#on-the-fly), but that has to be set within the application's entry point. This doesn't really solve our problem, because we want our `index.html` to load the main application chunk from the CDN as well. In other words, the `script` tag that Webpack injects into the HTML file (using HTMLWebpackPlugin) needs to incorporate the proper CDN host.

What's our best option here? Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1):

Interesting. I get your point about building binaries once, but logically you need different index.html files per stage of the pipeline with this architecture. It would be simpler if the index.html file was also deployed to the CDN.

In your setup I would aim for the results of the (complex) build process to be an `index.html.template` file, perhaps containing environment variables such as `$CDN_URL`. Then, for each stage of the pipeline, a (simple) deployment script could run a tool such as envsubst to supply final values and produce its index.html file.

If this doesn't play nicely with particular build tools, eg the HTML Webpack plugin, then it is relatively simple to do the right thing in a post webpack script, as in [this example](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/blob/master/spa/build/rewriteIndexHtml.ts) of mine.